# scanning spaces from stdin in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to scan some commands from stdin using the standard "fmt" package

However it seems that scanf stops after the first space.   Any idea how I can fix it?

```
   var in string
   for err != nil {
        _, err = fmt.Scanf("%s", &in)
    }
   fmt.Println(in)
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that what I needed was in the [bufio.Scan](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewScanner) package

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        return scanner.Text()
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
    }
```