# Read multi word string from console

Tags: go

I realized that the following only reads a single word string -

```
fmt.Scan(&sentence)
```

How do I read multi word string - as in, the string `sentence` should store a string that contains multiple words.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scanning spaces from stdin in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071813/scanning-spaces-from-stdin-in-go)

Comment: Very similar to the referenced link, but probably not as "googleable". OP - you should take a look at the [bufio](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/) package (as also pointed to in that link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question refers to scanning space separated input. The definition of `fmt.Scan` https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scan states:

```
Scan scans text read from standard input, storing successive space-
separated values into successive arguments. Newlines count as space.
It returns the number of items successfully scanned. If that is less
than the number of arguments, err will report why.
```

So, by definition, input is scanned up until the first space is found. To scan, let's say until you hit a `\n` on the command line you can use the code from the comment [scanning spaces from stdin in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071813/scanning-spaces-from-stdin-in-go):

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for scanner.Scan() {
    return scanner.Text()
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
}
```

Also this thread might be useful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/r6Jl4D9Juw0

Answer (score 5):

One can use the `InputReader` also to scan and print multiple words from the console.

The **solution code** is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    inputReader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input, _ := inputReader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(input)
}
```

**Console Input:**

Let's Go!!!

**Console Output:**

Let's Go!!!

Note:

To run a GOLANG program, open the command prompt or powershell, navigate to the directory where the program file is present and type in the following command:

```
go run file_name.go
```